# Accessors not printing out the correct output

Tags: java, accessor

I'm trying to get my program to print each of the 4 variables (*wholeNumber, decimalPart, positive, currencySymbol*) defined in the program below using an accessor for each, however when I go to run the program instead of getting this

**Expected Output:**

```
1
2
true
$
```

I instead get this. Could someone explain what error is causing this?

[CURRENT OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geyGX.png)

**CODE**

```
public class Q4 {

    int wholeNumber;
    int decimalPart;
    boolean positive;
    char currencySymbol;

    public Q4(int wholeNumber, int decimalPart, boolean positive, char currencySymbol){

    }
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Q4 m = new Q4(1,2,true,'$');
        System.out.println(m.getWholeNumber());
        System.out.println(m.getDecimalPart());
        System.out.println(m.isPositive());
        System.out.println(m.getCurrencySymbol());
    }

    // Accessor
    public int getWholeNumber(){
        return(wholeNumber);
    }

    // Accessor
    public int getDecimalPart(){
        return(decimalPart);
    }

    // Accessor
    public boolean isPositive(){
        return(positive);
    }

    // Accessor
    public char getCurrencySymbol(){
        return(currencySymbol);
    }

}
```

Comment: You have an empty constructor.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help others, please include your "current output" as text in your question, instead of linking to an external service. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the member variables in the constructor, so they are left at their default values.

```
public Q4(int wholeNumber, int decimalPart, boolean positive, char currencySymbol){
    this.wholeNumber = wholeNumber;
    this.decimalPart = decimalPart;
    this.positive = positive;
    this.currencySymbol = currencySymbol;
}
```